# Twisted HTTPS Client

Tags: python, https, twisted

I am currently having some trouble accessing content hosted via https using the twisted python library. I am new to this library, and am assuming there is some concept I am missing that's causing the issue, but perhaps not based upon the example.

Here is a link to the page in which I gathered the example: 
https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/web/howto/client.html

Under the heading **HTTP over SSL**

```html
from twisted.python.log import err
from twisted.web.client import Agent
from twisted.internet import reactor
from twisted.internet.ssl import optionsForClientTLS

def display(response):
    print("Received response")
    print(response)

def main():
    contextFactory = optionsForClientTLS(u"https://example.com/")
    agent = Agent(reactor, contextFactory)
    d = agent.request("GET", "https://example.com/")
    d.addCallbacks(display, err)
    d.addCallback(lambda ignored: reactor.stop())
    reactor.run()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

When running this code, it straight up fails. I get an error that looks like this:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "https.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "https.py", line 11, in main
    contextFactory = optionsForClientTLS(u"https://example.com/")
  File "/home/amaricich/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1336, in optionsForClientTLS
    return ClientTLSOptions(hostname, certificateOptions.getContext())
  File "/home/amaricich/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 1198, in __init__
    self._hostnameBytes = _idnaBytes(hostname)
  File "/home/amaricich/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/_sslverify.py", line 86, in _idnaBytes
    return idna.encode(text)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/idna/core.py", line 355, in encode
    result.append(alabel(label))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/idna/core.py", line 276, in alabel
    check_label(label)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/idna/core.py", line 253, in check_label
    raise InvalidCodepoint('Codepoint {0} at position {1} of {2} not allowed'.format(_unot(cp_value), pos+1, repr(label)))
idna.core.InvalidCodepoint: Codepoint U+003A at position 6 of u'https://example' not allowed
```

This error lead me to believe the parameter being passed into **optionsForClientTLS** were incorrect. It calls for a hostname and not a full url, so I shortened the parameter to simply **example.com**. Once that change was made, the function completed successfully.

Unfortunately though, after making the change, the script now failed at the line invoking **agent.request**. The error it supplied was this:

```html
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "https.py", line 19, in <module>
    main()
  File "https.py", line 13, in main
    d = agent.request("GET", "https://example.com/")
  File "/home/amaricich/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1596, in request
    endpoint = self._getEndpoint(parsedURI)
  File "/home/amaricich/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1580, in _getEndpoint
    return self._endpointFactory.endpointForURI(uri)
  File "/home/amaricich/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 1456, in endpointForURI
    uri.port)
  File "/home/amaricich/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/web/client.py", line 982, in creatorForNetloc
    context = self._webContextFactory.getContext(hostname, port)
AttributeError: 'ClientTLSOptions' object has no attribute 'getContext'
```

This error leads me to believe that the object being produced by optionsForClientTLS is not the object type that is expected to be passed into the Agent upon creation. A function is trying to be invoked that does not exist. With all that said, I have two questions.

1. Is this example deprecated? The previous examples that make http requests all work like a charm. Am I doing something wrong, or is the example no longer valid?
2. I am only looking for a simple way to retrieve data from a server using HTTPS. If doing things this way is not the solution, is anyone familiar with how HTTPS requests can be made using twisted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you're absolutely correct that the example on the docs is wrong. I noticed the bug [while working w/ `treq`](https://github.com/twisted/treq/issues/65#issuecomment-249660064). Try following [this example](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/14.0.0/web/howto/client.html#http-over-ssl) from v14. With that being said, you should use [`treq`](https://treq.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) as opposed to trying to use Twisted directly. Most of the heavy lifting has been taken care of for you. Here's an simple conversion of your example:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import treq
from twisted.internet import defer, task
from twisted.python.log import err

@defer.inlineCallbacks
def display(response):
    content = yield treq.content(response)
    print('Content: {0}'.format(content))

def main(reactor):
    d = treq.get('https://twistedmatrix.com')
    d.addCallback(display)
    d.addErrback(err)
    return d

task.react(main)
```

As you can see `treq` takes care of the SSL stuff for you. The `display()` callback function can be used to extract various components of the HTTP response, such as headers, status codes, body, etc. If you only need a single component, such as the response body, then you can simplify further like so:

```
def main(reactor):
    d = treq.get('https://twistedmatrix.com')
    d.addCallback(treq.content)     # get response content when available
    d.addErrback(err)
    d.addCallback(print)
    return d

task.react(main)
```

Comment: You are a saint! Thank you so much for your help. Treq works great and will allow me to continue with my work. You are a gem and I appreciate you and everything you do.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :D Good to hear people use Python/Twisted in the DMV area.