# Curl -u in scrapy

Tags: python, curl, web-scraping, scrapy

How to do this curl on scrapy?

```
curl –i -u account_id:api_key 
"https://xecdapi.xe.com/v1/convert_from.json/?from=USD&to=CAD,EUR 
&amount=110.23"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer!!!

Scrapy does not allow HTTP Basic Auth via URL or `Authorization` header because of a bug in Twisted [Twisted HTTPS Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40750603/twisted-https-client).

We have to use a not so famous middleware, HTTPAuthMiddleware https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/docs/topics/downloader-middleware.rst#httpauthmiddleware

To use it, activate the middleware in the `settings.py` like this:

```
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware': 811,
}
```

And add these attributes to the spider.

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider

class SomeIntranetSiteSpider(CrawlSpider):

    http_user = 'someuser'
    http_pass = 'somepass'
    name = 'intranet.example.com'

    # .. rest of the spider code omitted ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `scrapy fetch` command:

```
scrapy fetch http://stackoverflow.com --nolog > output.html
```

To use authentication you can try passing credentials via url itself:

```
scrapy fetch "http://username:password@stackoverflow.com" --nolog > output.html
```

Comment: I want to do it inside the spider

Comment: And I get 500 Internal Server Error again using Scrapy fetch

Comment: @AminahNuraini but that not what it says in your question; I see you have another question open that does indicate that you want to do it in spider, so maybe you should make it more clear and keep one question open that describes your issue fully.

Comment: Doesn't matter anyway. Scrapy fetch and inside spider gives the same result anyway